# Android calculate bounding box for mapview

Tags: android, gis, android-mapview, android-maps, bounding-box

I am not using Google maps or Openstreet maps. I am using another [third party custom maps](https://github.com/tangrams/tangram-es/tree/master/android) which do not provide any bounding box classes or methods. So What i want to achieve is to zoom to fit all markers on the map or zoom to route drawn on map. Like Google provide `LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;` classes and OpenStreetMaps provides `zoomToBoundingBox()` to achieve this functionality. I only have latlng points and map dimensions width/height. How can i calculate bounds or bounding box zoom level for markers or route drawn on map to fit it to screen? Any formula or mathematical calculations?

Comment: Unfortunately "another third party custom maps" isn't enough to say anything about calculating zoom levels, so you could edit your question to specify the map provider and some more relevant details.

Comment: ok thanks for suggestion. I have edited my question